# When i run my Fragment project, eclipse shows errors. I don't know how to fix it

Tags: android

Here is the instruction i tried to follow carefully:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/fragment/android-fragments-example/

here are the first errors appear in Logcat:

E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(21404): Parent view is not a TextView

E/AndroidRuntime(21404): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime(21404): Process: com.example.fragmentstest, PID: 21404

E/AndroidRuntime(21404): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragmentstest/com.example.fragmentstest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class fragment

here are my MainActivity and activity_main codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void selectFrag(View view){
    Fragment fr;
    if (view == findViewById(R.id.button2)){
        fr = new FragmentTwo();
    } else {
        fr = new FragmentOne();
    }
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();


}  




<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fragment No.1"
    android:onClick="selectFrag" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fragment No.2" 
    android:onClick="selectFrag"/>

<fragment 
    android:name="com.example.fragmentstest.FragmentOne"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>"

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have the fragment in your package ? com.example.fragmentstest.FragmentOne should match exactly the class name of your Fragment in your package

Comment: hmm it should be 
<com.example.fragmentstest.FragmentOne
android:id= ....
android:layout...
/>

Comment: It's not the problem. i got my eyes on it!

Comment: Well there are errors in your xml as well. Try to post something understandable if you want to get help easily. Here there is an obvious mistake in your xml.

Comment: Please try to clean and build your project again. That might solve it

Comment: Is there a way to post my project.zip so that you could see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find the error cause. It's a logic error (hard to find).
In both FragmentOne.java and FragmentTwo.java, i returned activity_main.xml instead of fragment_one.xml and fragment_two.xml as the source layout.
Sorry if the problem doesn't lie down in the information i provided in the question body. but at least now i know more!

Here is the sample code:

```
   public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
   ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   //I had to use fragment_one instead of activity_main.
   //Such simple mistake took about two days of my time.

  return inflater.inflate(
          R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
  }
```